# Categorize text as Body, Heading in a loosely formatted document

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, text

> Given a semi-structured document with only texts and images, and some style properties present on the text, What is
>   the best possible way to classify the text present in the document to
>   any formal HTML standard class such as Heading, Body, Caption, List
>   etc.

PS: Please forgive me if you think the question is highly abstract, but the task I am attempting can be broadly categorized in this way only. I need to extract structure from a loosely structured document. Any suggestions to this incorporating ML/Heuristics or links to any such existing problems/existing solutions will be deeply appreciated as well.

[image]

Comment: Try appending some sample data, so that we can understand how the data looks like and we can suggest you accordingly

Comment: You want to extract the inbetween stuffs between html tags?

Comment: If my guess is right, he wants to segregate the set of lines into Subject, Body, Head etc, given the semi-structured document.

Comment: I've attached a sample document. The text is random, but notice that there is a font size difference for heading and body text, and there are bullets added in a part of the body text.

Comment: So you need to classify the document text into Heading, Body, List etc right? if yes, where/how are you planning to use ML?

Comment: Well this is exactly where i need help in. Do i treat each document as an image, or use a set of heuristics like font size, text position for classifying, or any other approach?

Comment: I think going through this [paper](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-710/paper23.pdf) might give you a good idea on performing the task. when you comment do tag me if you are replying or else I wont receive a notification.

Comment: @Toros91 Yes this is the kind of broad idea I am trying to imbibe. However, to be more specific, legal documents still contain a lot of structure. The documents I am targetting could be brochures, pamphlets or even audit reports or medical reports. Given any type of document, is there any research that could with a reasonable confidence ratio classify text blocks in any standard class?

Comment: @AbhaySibal Thanks for the sample! What is the digital document format? Are these images or do you have some kind of structured document?

Comment: The document can be assumed to be a standard Word document containing rich text, annotation, graphics, links, and formatting. You can assume that I can query the page objects, and get their dimensions, and also get the applied formatting parameters on a piece of text @SvanBalen

Comment: Hi @Toros91, any leads mate?

Comment: @AbhaySibal: I'm really very sorry man, I tried but dint get any leads. The reason is It is very hard to generalize it(one model for everything). The above approach is applicable only on structured data. Will be looking out for you and if I find any leads would update you.

Comment: @AbhaySibal so if I now respond with Beautiful Soup, you say: "Check"? From there i have done this in a production setting with manual wrappers (regexp), not really fast, but recall high enough for that case.